# How to stop alert once it had been successfully triggered?

Tags: javascript, firebase, d3.js

I am working with Javascript with D3, and firebase. Not XML Http request.

The difficulty I am having is how to introduce a while loop and boolean to alert my message once it has been successfully executed.

In other words, when they pass the 20% mark, it should alert them once, when I refresh the page, it should not alert them again. I used alert as a reference guide because as a beginner, that is the only novice function I can use. If there alternatives way to achieve the results without alert() function but can alert(notify) users, that would be great.

I am thinking

var boolean = true

while  (...)  <--not sure how

boolean = false; after my alert is triggered.  Since I am a beginner in javascript, the for loop is required because the data is read and put into D3 javascript chart.

My question is how do I introduce a while loop to check the conditions and booleans but still have the for loop inside. SAFE and shouldn't go to infinite loop.

I tried a variety, but debugging is difficult.

```
  var data = snapshot.val();
  var dataArray = [];



  for (var number in data)
  {
    var percentage = data[number].Percentage;

    dataArray.push({valorX: data[number].Team, valorY: percentage});
        if(percentage >="0.2" && percentage <= "0.39")
        {
            alert("Congratulations Team " + data[key].Team + "\nYou have passed the 20% mark!");
        } else if (percentage >= "0.4" && percentage <= "0.59")
        {
           alert("Congratulations Team " + data[key].Team + "\nYou have passed the 40% mark!");
        }
        else
        {
            console.log(percentage);


  }
  }
```

Comment: @Maerin  Hi, i don't see how it is a duplicate to the thread you cited. Mine is D3 javascript, firebase and json,  not xml http request.

Comment: If you want to preserve variable state after refresh also, you will need to use some browser storage. ex - localstorage or sessionStorage, to store that alert has been fired once.

Comment: @RonnWilder thank you, that is correct and if I had a connection with a database (real-time) updating the data (without refresh) would I need this too?  I assume it is more related to my issues in coding in that specific area, but as for refresh related, i agree with you on that.

Comment: What information are you updating in database?

Comment: @test: You're right, I thought you wanted to remove the alert box after triggering it.

Comment: @RonnWilder percentages, it is large amount of data, so data will be changing every 5-10 seconds, last thing I want is a localstorage or sessionStorages firing everytime when the percentages changes, as it reads from changes in last value. The localstorage and sessionstorage will definitely help in situations when values become unchanged for period of time, but not so much when it is updated a lot (in my situation).

Comment: can you set a variable one level higher than this function: `have_given_20percent_alert = false` and `have_given_40percent_alert = false`. Then add  those values to your if condition, and changing them to `true` when you fire the alert?

Comment: @SherylHohman, hi Sheryl, thanks for your response. Are you suggesting that the boolean should go outside my function as a global level rather within so it as you correctly mention, if it re-fires again, the condition boolean set to true on global level would not retrigger?

Comment: @SherylHohman I tried your suggestion, in theory it wasn't a bad idea and it should have worked, but when I implemented this, unfortunately the conditions still retriggers.

Comment: What I am getting is, you are pulling data from database using (snapshot.val) and plotting it on d3 team vs percentage. Now you want to notify users about each 20% marks (20, 40, 60, 80, 100). Is that right?

Comment: If that is the case, just use your if else in reverse order, and use global object to keep track of which team you already notified.
if(percentage > 80 && percentage < 100)
else if(percentage > 60 && percentage < 80) and so on...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use variable to store the status. Use browser storage to persist status.

```
var data = snapshot.val();
var dataArray = [];

var status = window.localStorage.getItem('status') ? JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem('status')) : {};

for (var number in data)
{
  var percentage = data[number].Percentage;
  // set team name as key
  var key = data[number].Team;
  var current = status[key] ? status[key] : {}

  dataArray.push({valorX: data[number].Team, valorY: percentage});
    if(percentage >="0.2" && percentage <= "0.39" && !current.twenty2fourty)
    {
        alert("Congratulations Team " + data[key].Team + "\nYou have passed the 20% mark!");
        current.twenty2fourty = true;
        window.localStorage.setItem('status', JSON.stringify(status));
    } else if (percentage >= "0.4" && percentage <= "0.59" && !current.fourty2sixty)
    {
       alert("Congratulations Team " + data[key].Team + "\nYou have passed the 40% mark!");
       current.fourty2sixty = true;
       window.localStorage.setItem('status', JSON.stringify(status));
    }
    else
    {
        console.log(percentage);
    }
  }
```

Then status then should have a format of:

```
{
  "team1": {"twenty2fourty" : true},
  "team2": {"fourty2sixty" : true},
  "team3": {"twenty2fourty" : true, "fourty2sixty": true}
}
```

Comment: thanks for your patience Mengo, I had been UAT your previous code.    it works fine on one bar,   but I had to change the status condition between 20 and 40 percentage as when 20 condition was triggered, it did not trigger 40 percentage.    overall, it works fine for only one team.  the complexity is when there is more than one team. the conditions between multiple teams are shared.   there are a few ways I can work around it, but not as very clean code as you have written it.  (because I am still a beginner).   the change was in your edit was good, but JSON stringify did not work.

Comment: please wait until I test Ronn Wilder, and I wil return back on which should be approved answer. thanks!

Comment: I've updated the answer. Just assign a key to each team so that each step in the loop are checking corresponding key.

Comment: thank you Mengo, on my side, the JSON.stringify doesn't work.   http://imgur.com/a/TK6WQ     but your expertise and professional work on this is far valued and appreciated, thank you for going out of your way to really help me on this.   unfortunately, I will keep on continuing to debug as it says JSON,  unexpected character at Line 1 Column 1.   Thank you, and ill update you response when I see progress

Comment: Due to JSON.stringify issues and firebase, I had to resort to var status = window.localStorage.getItem('status') || null;  your previous code and I relaxed the percentages to 20-23  and 40-43 instead. It is not the best way to do it, but I will continue to learn more about javascript until I can be competent. So far you have given me so much help and knowledge that I didn't know it was possible at all in javascript, thank you very much Mengo.  I will use this as an approved answer because it will probably help someone that uses a database other than firebase

Comment: {
  "team1": {"twenty2fourty" : true},
  "team2": {"fourty2sixty" : true},
  "team3": {"twenty2fourty" : true, "fourty2sixty": true},
}   I found that the extra comma at the end invalids the json.

Comment: glad to be helpful, the trailing comma is removed.

Answer (score 0):

```
var alertObj = {};

for (var number in data)
    {
        var percentage = data[number].Percentage;
        var key;

        dataArray.push({valorX: data[number].Team, valorY: percentage});
                if(percentage >="0.2" && percentage <= "0.39")
                {
                        key = data[number].Team + "--20%"
                        if(!alertObj[key]){
                            alert("Congratulations Team " + data[key].Team + "\nYou have passed the 20% mark!");    
                        }
                        else {
                            alertObj[key] = true;
                        }


                } else if (percentage >= "0.4" && percentage <= "0.59")
                {
                        key = data[number].Team + "--40%"
                        if(!alertObj[key]){
                            alert("Congratulations Team " + data[key].Team + "\nYou have passed the 40% mark!");
                        }
                        else {
                            alertObj[key] = true;
                        }

                }
                else
                {
                        console.log(percentage);


    }
    }
```

key will be in format "{teamname}--20" in case of 20%.
this way you can keep track of which team is notified of which mark.

Comment: And if you want to cover refresh case also, store this alertObj in localStorage or sessionStorage.